# Wish list management

Tags: shopping-cart, shopping, wishlist

I just want a site to manage my wishlist. a few things that I would like are

- basic stuff like price, name, and link
- price tracking
- cheapest store
- Multiple lists

if you know anything, that would be great.

I would prefer a tracker free solution, or at least one who only takes browser details ect. and not my actual data. Self hosting solutions are welcome. In terms of backups, a feature to backup would be nice, in case the site goes under.